# Android sdk17 in ubuntuStudio creating Buildingcache.java insread of R.java

Tags: android, ubuntu-11.10

Hey I am using ubuntu Studio and sdk17 with compatible adt in ubuntu but android project has R.java file missing I have created new project as well ,clean the project ,build it but none of thing solved my problem ...

Comment: Do you have 3rd party libraries in your project?. In which folder they are?

Comment: no I am noy using any third party library instead i am using api demo too they are also not working i think some problem with sdk will be there

Comment: $sudo apt-get install ia32-libs will solve your problem

Comment: thanks I got it work in the past with the same solution